# Expresión regular documento json

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy tratando de realizar una expresión regular que me permita reparar este tipo de registros para poder convertirlos en un objeto.

```
"[{"idUsuario":"3","nombreCompleto":"Edisson Fernando Ruiz Sandoval","comentarioInspe":" 1.11 ID; 0.118in","fecha":"3-4-03 16:28:32"},{"idUsuario":"3","nombreCompleto":"Edisson Fernando Ruiz Sandoval","comentarioInspe":"adicional 1.11" ID; 0.118"in","fecha":"3-4-03 10:05:16"}]"
```

ya he utilizado las siguientes pero no logro remplazar solo esas

````
([a-z0-9]\"[a-z0-9]) // => el problema con esta es que me remplaza también los elementos alrededor 
(?!(?=(\{\"[a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9]\"\:\"|[a-z0-9]\"\,\"))) 
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No soy muy diestro en expresiones regulares y, seguramente, debe haber mejores formas de hacer lo que buscas.

Al parecer, la cadena no se puede convertir en objeto porque incluye comillas dobles en los extremos y dentro de algunos valores. Una opción es recorrer cada caracter para analizar si debe cambiarse o no:

```js
let str = '"[{"idUsuario":"3","nombreCompleto":"Edisson Fernando Ruiz Sandoval","comentarioInspe":" 1.11 ID; 0.118in","fecha":"3-4-03 16:28:32"},{"idUsuario":"3","nombreCompleto":"Edisson Fernando Ruiz Sandoval","comentarioInspe":"adicional 1.11" ID; 0.118"in","fecha":"3-4-03 10:05:16"}]"';
// Eliminar comillas en los extremos
str = str.substr(1, str.length - 2);
// Inicializar nueva cadena
let newStr = '';
// Recorrer cadena, caracter por caracter
for(let index = 0; index < str.length; index ++) {
    let char = str[index];
    // Si el caracter actual es comillas dobles
    // Y está dentro de propiedad o valor
    if(char == '"'
    && !['{', '[', ':', ','].includes(str[index - 1])
    && !['}', ']', ':', ','].includes(str[index + 1])) {
        // Remplazar comillas dobles
        newStr += '&quot;';
        // Si prefieres eliminar, comenta la línea anterior
    } else {
        // Agregar caracter normal
        newStr += char;
    }
}
// Convertir en objeto
let data = JSON.parse(newStr);
console.log(data);
```